# How to configure SOLR for handling similar search keywords: `ABCWord`, `abc word`?

Tags: solr

I have content with two title types: `ABCWord` & `ABC Word`. When I put to search box keywords like: `abc-word`, `abc word` content titled `ABC  Word` is found, but I need to get also `ABCWord` titled content.

I've tried to use: `solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory` and `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` for it, but it seems I'm using it wrong.

My current `schema.xml` text field configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="back"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="back"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using it wrong, but maybe you're using too much filters that are affecting the final result.
The EdgeNGram should resolve your problem, since it'll create tokens from size 3 to 30 in your input. So, "ABCWord" will become "abc", "abcw", "abcwo", "abcwor" and "abcword", and then a search for "abc" should match.

First of all, I'd recommend you to change the fieldType you're using when you use ngram, because it'll increase **a lot** your index size. It's better to create a new field type to use only in fields you really need it, instead of the "text" fieldType that probably indexes others values where you don't need ngrams.

Second, if your analyzer definition can be the same for index and search time, you don't need to duplicate the configs, just use 'analyzer' instead of 'analyzer type="index"' and 'analyzer type="query"'.

I strongly recommend you to check the analysis tab in your solr admin to see how Solr processes the indexed and queried text for your input. You can also remove some of the filters in your fieldType config when you're trying to achieve some specific result. It's better to understand what each filter is doing to your input.